# Make percent complete (jQuery + php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to make percent complete (process bar) which show me how much data is processed.
This is my php code:

```
$w->connect();
try {
    $w->loginWithPassword($password);
}
catch (exception $e) {
    return false;
}
foreach($targets as $target)
{
    $w->sendMessage($target, $text);
}
return true;
```

foreach is process which I want to show how many message is sent.
now in js I have:

```
  function send_message(){
  var msg =  {msg_receptions:$('#msg_receptions').val(),msg_from:$('#msg_from').val(),msg_text:    $('#msg_text').val()};
$.post(
         site_url('ajax/send_message'),
         msg,
         function(data, status){

         }
       );
  }
```

I do not know how to make process bar to show percent complete!

Answer (score 2):

Edit based on comments.

If you want to track how many of your messages have been uploaded, then you need to do a polling system into a current session (you could do with sockets, but that's getting complicated).

In the PHP, start a session (before loading the first page) and create session variable to store the progress. In the page you post to, use the same session, set progress to 0 and every time the `SendMessage` loops, update that variable with latest progress.

In the JS, submit the PHP request using AJAX (so the HTML stays) and then use `setTimeout()` to do a second AJAX request to new file you need to write that uses the same session, grabs the updated progress data and returns it - that will be the same as the initial answer. When you get a response, do `setTimeout` again and repeat (don't use `setInterval` as you can crash a server doing that). When the initial request returns, kill the timeout.

Final note: using jQueryUI is overkill for this; so only use it if you have other stuff you're using it for. Otherwise it's 10 lines of code (below).

Hope that helps / answers the question.

** Previous Answer **

The easiest way of doing this is two wrap two divs inside each other.

Your stylesheet should contain:

```
<style>
    .progressBar {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;  /* Style as you see fit */
    }
    .progressIndicator {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 10%;
        background: #f00;  /* Style as you see fit */
    }
</style>
```

Your HTML should contain

```
<html>
    <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="progressIndicator">
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Your javascript (jQuery) response should contain

```
$('.progressIndicator').css({width: parseInt(data, 10) + "%"});
```

(Where data is the value returned between 0 and 100)

Comment: Nice answer, +1, so close to that 10k too ;)

Comment: No,It is not my answer.I want to get real process percent complete. I can make process bar with jquery ui.

Comment: As in how much data has been uploaded? Or is the login taking a long time and you want to know how far that login process has progressed?

Comment: I want to send message which take lots of time then I want to show many message sent.